# Matterport E57 file

Tags: lidar, pcd

What CLI tools can I used to convert e57 to pcd/obj files?

I am trying to show my users the 3d representation of a scanned building taken by a lidar camera on a map, I think version 3 camera, I don't have physical access to it and am only being provided a large .e57 file.

I see many cloud service that say they can process this into a a PCD or OBJ file. Which I can than embed/display on a web based viewer using three.js & mapboxgl.js. But, I want to be able to create my own pcd/obj or model type files because the business will have hundreds to thousands of scans in the future. I want to automate this processing at scale.

I am very experienced mapbox developer but fairly new to lidar in general.

How and what would I use, what command line tools can convert these e57 files into pcd or obj files which I can use to display the building (and at some point place the buildings in their correct location on a map). GIS stack exchange is not the most relevant I know but I have googled for weeks now, posted to normal stack exchange and cannot get any answers.

What CLI tools can I used to convert e57 to pcd/obj files?